# Find paths from one table to another over keys

Tags: sql, t-sql

For example;

I have 500 tables in database. One table is named "Table1" and another "Table234". I need to join "Table1" and "Table234" but I can't join them directly, I need to use other tables. Is it possible to make query where I enter starting table (in this case Table1) and ending table (in this case Table234) and it finds all possible paths over keys from starting to ending table.

Let's say that I have two possible paths:

- Table1 -> Table 23 -> Table456 -> Table234
- Table1 -> Table 34 -> Table23 -> Zable 456 -> Table234

  Select * from table1

  join table23 on XX = XX

  join table456 on XX = XX

  join table234 on XX = XX

Maybe something like BFS to find shortest path, and than save it somewhere and find BFS without that path?

Solution (@Geoff Patterson):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#paths') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #paths

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#shortestPaths') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #shortestPaths
GO

DECLARE @targetObjectName SYSNAME = 'YourTableNameHere'

;WITH singleColumnFkColumns AS (

    SELECT fk1.*
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fk1
    LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fk2 ON fk2.constraint_object_id = fk1.constraint_object_id AND fk2.constraint_column_id = 2
    WHERE fk1.constraint_column_id = 1
        AND fk2.constraint_object_id IS NULL
)
, parentCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        p.object_id AS ParentId
        ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) + '.' + p.name AS ParentTable
        ,pc.column_id AS ParentColumnId
        ,pc.name AS ParentColumn
        ,r.object_id AS ChildId
        ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(r.object_id) + '.' + r.name AS ChildTable
        ,rc.column_id AS ChildColumnId
        ,rc.name AS ChildColumn
        ,1 AS depth

        ,   ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.object_id) + '_NULL_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), pc.column_id) +
            ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), r.object_id) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), pc.column_id) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), rc.column_id) AS TraversalPath
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fk
    JOIN sys.columns pc ON pc.object_id = fk.parent_object_id AND pc.column_id = fk.parent_column_id 
    JOIN sys.columns rc ON rc.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = fk.referenced_column_id
    JOIN sys.tables p ON p.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
    JOIN sys.tables r ON r.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
    WHERE fk.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@targetObjectName)
        AND p.object_id <> r.object_id 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        p.object_id AS ParentId
        ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) + '.' + p.name AS ParentTable
        ,pc.column_id AS ParentColumnId
        ,pc.name AS ParentColumn
        ,r.object_id AS ChildId
        ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(r.object_id) + '.' + r.name AS ChildTable
        ,rc.column_id AS ChildColumnId
        ,rc.name AS ChildColumn
        ,cte.depth + 1 AS depth
        ,cte.TraversalPath + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), r.object_id) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), pc.column_id) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), rc.column_id) AS TraversalPath
    FROM parentCTE cte
    JOIN singleColumnFkColumns fk
        ON fk.parent_object_id = cte.ChildId
    JOIN sys.columns pc ON pc.object_id = fk.parent_object_id AND pc.column_id = fk.parent_column_id 
    JOIN sys.columns rc ON rc.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = fk.referenced_column_id
    JOIN sys.tables p ON p.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
    JOIN sys.tables r ON r.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
    WHERE p.object_id <> r.object_id 
        AND cte.TraversalPath NOT LIKE ('%_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), r.object_id) + '%')
)
SELECT *
INTO #paths
FROM parentCTE
ORDER BY depth, ParentTable, ChildTable
GO

SELECT *
INTO #shortestPaths
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ChildTable ORDER BY depth ASC) AS rankToThisChild
    FROM #paths
) x
WHERE rankToThisChild = 1
ORDER BY ChildTable
GO

WITH joinCTE AS (

    SELECT p.ChildTable
        , p.TraversalPath AS ParentTraversalPath
        , NULL AS depth
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 'FROM ' + p.ChildTable + ' t' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.depth+1)) AS JoinString
    FROM #shortestPaths p

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.ChildTable
        , REPLACE(p.TraversalPath, ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, p.ChildId) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, p.ParentColumnId)+ '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, p.ChildColumnId), '') AS TraversalPath
        , p.depth
        , cte.JoinString + '
' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 'JOIN ' + p.ParentTable + ' t' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.depth) + ' ON t' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.depth) + '.' + p.ParentColumn + ' = t' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.depth+1) + '.' + p.ChildColumn) AS JoinString
    FROM joinCTE cte
    JOIN #paths p
        ON p.TraversalPath = cte.ParentTraversalPath
)

SELECT ChildTable, 'SELECT TOP 100 * 
' +JoinString
FROM joinCTE
WHERE depth = 1
ORDER BY ChildTable
GO
```

You can replace "YourTableNameHere" in script and it will find You all links to from any to that table.

And in my JAVA software looks like:

```
RS = CALIzb.main(Conn, "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#paths') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #paths IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#shortestPaths') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #shortestPaths  DECLARE @targetObjectName SYSNAME = '"+txtTablica.getText().trim()+"' ;WITH singleColumnFkColumns AS ( SELECT fk1.* FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fk1 LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fk2 ON fk2.constraint_object_id = fk1.constraint_object_id AND fk2.constraint_column_id = 2 WHERE fk1.constraint_column_id = 1 AND fk2.constraint_object_id IS NULL ), parentCTE AS ( SELECT  p.object_id AS ParentId ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) + '.' + p.name AS ParentTable,pc.column_id AS ParentColumnId,pc.name AS ParentColumn,r.object_id AS ChildId,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(r.object_id) + '.' + r.name AS ChildTable,rc.column_id AS ChildColumnId,rc.name AS ChildColumn,1 AS depth,   ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.object_id) + '_NULL_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), pc.column_id) +',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), r.object_id) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), pc.column_id) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), rc.column_id) AS TraversalPath FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fk JOIN sys.columns pc ON pc.object_id = fk.parent_object_id AND pc.column_id = fk.parent_column_id  JOIN sys.columns rc ON rc.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = fk.referenced_column_id JOIN sys.tables p ON p.object_id = fk.parent_object_id JOIN sys.tables r ON r.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id WHERE fk.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@targetObjectName) AND p.object_id <> r.object_id  UNION ALL SELECT  p.object_id AS ParentId,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) + '.' + p.name AS ParentTable,pc.column_id AS ParentColumnId,pc.name AS ParentColumn,r.object_id AS ChildId,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(r.object_id) + '.' + r.name AS ChildTable,rc.column_id AS ChildColumnId,rc.name AS ChildColumn,cte.depth + 1 AS depth,cte.TraversalPath + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), r.object_id) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), pc.column_id) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), rc.column_id) AS TraversalPath FROM parentCTE cte JOIN singleColumnFkColumns fk ON fk.parent_object_id = cte.ChildId JOIN sys.columns pc ON pc.object_id = fk.parent_object_id AND pc.column_id = fk.parent_column_id  JOIN sys.columns rc ON rc.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = fk.referenced_column_id JOIN sys.tables p ON p.object_id = fk.parent_object_id JOIN sys.tables r ON r.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id WHERE p.object_id <> r.object_id  AND cte.TraversalPath NOT LIKE ('%_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), r.object_id) + '%')) SELECT * INTO #paths FROM parentCTE ORDER BY depth, ParentTable, ChildTable SELECT * INTO #shortestPaths FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ChildTable ORDER BY depth ASC) AS rankToThisChild FROM #paths) x WHERE rankToThisChild = 1 ORDER BY ChildTable");
                RS = CALIzb.main(Conn, "WITH joinCTE AS ( SELECT p.ChildTable, p.TraversalPath AS ParentTraversalPath, NULL AS depth, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 'FROM ' + p.ChildTable + ' t' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.depth+1)) AS JoinString FROM #shortestPaths p UNION ALL SELECT cte.ChildTable, REPLACE(p.TraversalPath, ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, p.ChildId) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, p.ParentColumnId)+ '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, p.ChildColumnId), '') AS TraversalPath, p.depth, cte.JoinString + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 'JOIN ' + p.ParentTable + ' t' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.depth) + ' ON t' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.depth) + '.' + p.ParentColumn + ' = t' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), p.depth+1) + '.' + p.ChildColumn) AS JoinString FROM joinCTE cte JOIN #paths p ON p.TraversalPath = cte.ParentTraversalPath) SELECT ChildTable, 'SELECT TOP 100 * ' +JoinString FROM joinCTE WHERE depth = 1 ORDER BY ChildTable");
                vezaKljuceva.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(RS));
```

Comment: if you use sqlserver you can use sys.object and sys.column and sys.schema to see the relations and columns of tables but if you want find all path and it need to create a function to find all possible relation pathes to a table.

Comment: You can write a recursive CTE to use declared foreign key relationships for this purpose.  However, I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, write is as an answer (not by editing the question).